# Backend technology and architecture for an Angular map based app

Tags: angular, web, server, backend, ngrx

My team and I are developing a web application using Angular 7 which handles very dynamic data that consists of plots and similar data. The app displays the data in real-time on a map using Cesiumjs and (sort of) a table, allowing the users to perform different opeartions on the entities.

Currently, the app is polling a single server written in Java for multiple entity types through a different HTTP request for each type every 500ish miliseconds and receives the entire state of the application (most updated state of the plots, tracks etc...) as json. The application is then distributing it through the application using Ngrx Store.

There is also a nodejs service that handles user actions and authentication related issues.

The Java service is based on some legacy code, is complicated and big and is full of bugs, so the team decided we want to completely refactor the server side of the application. Its current job is:

- To serve as a listener of an external Pub-Sub network that publishes the data relevant to the application.
- Fuse the data  and store it in container classes in a way that suites the client
- Serve as an HTTP server for the client to query.

My questions are as following:

1. According to the latest say in server side technologies, what would be a good way to design and implement a server side for a real-time app like I just described? A constraint is that atleast some part has to be in Java because of the external Pub-sub network.
2. What is the best method to receive and handle data in an Angular application that works with Ngrx store? should we retrieve the entire state every HTTP request and "replace" the entire data state every cycle or should we move over to only retrieving relevant updates and handling that differently in the client? Is there maybe a third and better way to tackle this issue?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [nest.js](https://nestjs.com). It is a node.js framework with an underlying express instance and offers a very clear structure that is very similar to an Angular application, great testing tools,... Different messaging protocols are supported ([rabbitmq](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/rabbitmq), [nats](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/nats), [mqtt](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/mqtt), [redis](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/redis),...). (Why is java a requirement? Pub/Sub should be language independent?!)

Have you considered using [`ngrx/entity`](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity) for handling your data updates? I think it's hard to make a general suggestion here, but only sending the updates seems like a good idea. This way you can make use of memoized selectors and avoid unnecessary computations and renderings.

Comment: I'm going to have to dive inside to learn about nest.js, but from what I just read it seems like its heading in the right direction!
As for ngrx/entity, could you please elaborate more on how this is supposed to work alongisde the store?

Comment: Yeah, especially when you already know Angular. :-) `ngrx/entity` adds basic operations for entity management: add / update / delete etc. So you can send an update from your server (e.g. via a websocket connection) `delete id 1234` and let `ngrx/entity` handle it.